# delete row php&mysql dynamique link

Tags: php, mysql, get

I want to make a link to delete a record from database using dynamic links with php however i couldn't figure it out 
this is my code :

```
 <?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>

<table>
    <tr style="background: #afafaf;">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
<?php
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class=\"center\">".$rows['id']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$rows['title']."</td>";
            echo "<td><a href=\"delete_post.php?id=".$rows['id']."\"> delete</a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>
```

the output link would be like `.../delete.php?id=X`
can anyone help me write the code for `delete.php` ?

Comment: No we can not write the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the below code in your page. This first checks if `$_GET['id']` is set. It will only run if it is, that way you don't get **Undefined Index** error.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $deleteId = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES);

    $delete = "DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = " . $deleteId;
}
?>
```

I also used [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to sanitize the user input. You could run some validation using [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) to ensure that the input is actually an integer.

I suggest using prepared statement in MySQLi to prevent SQL injection.

**Edit 1**

Example with `ctype_digit`. This checks if the `id` is set and if it is a number, technically you could just use `ctype_digit` because if `id` is empty then `ctype` will return false as `var_dump(ctype_digit(""));` will return `false`, with that logic in mind, the value must be set for `ctype_digit` to work **and** it must be an integer.

```
<?php
if (ctype_digit($_GET['id'])) {
    $deleteId = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'], ENT_QUOTES);

    $delete = "DELETE FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = " . $deleteId;
}
?>
```

Comment: @user2030409 glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this:

```
$deleteId = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = ".$deleteId;
```

Remember to escape your variables before sending them off to the MySQL server.